# Pourquoi 'isocèle' et pas 'isoscèle'

Tags: orthographe, histoire, grec, évolution

En grec 'Ισο**σ**κελές' [iso**s**kelês,  du grec ancien ἴσος, isos (« égal ») et σκέλος, skêlos (« jambe »)] en espagnol 'isó**s**celes', en italien 'iso**s**cele', en anglais 'iso**s**celes', en roumain 'iso**s**cel'.

En français, il existe deux écritures 'isoscèle' et 'isocèle'. Mais la deuxième est beaucoup plus répandue comme ce [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=isoc%C3%A8le%2C%20isosc%C3%A8le&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) l'affirme. Plus précisément la première variante semble de disparaître quasiment à partir des années de 1980. Mes enfants me confirment aussi que c'est la deuxième variante qu'ils utilisent à l'école.

Quelle explication peut-on donner à cela ? Pourquoi la lettre *s* n'a pas été maintenue ? Pourquoi le français a-t-il adopté une orthographe différente ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Émile Littré pense comme toi :

> isocèle
> (i-zo-sè-l') adj.
> Voy. isoscèle. On ne voit pas pourquoi, en un mot purement technique, l'Académie adopte l'orthographe barbare isocèle, et rejette l'orthographe étymologique et correcte isoscèle.

Littré s'indigne de l'écart fait par l'Académie française par rapport à sa doctrine qui a toujours été de privilégier l'orthographe étymologique, qui plus est pour un mot qui n'est pas d'usage courant comme *isocèle* mais utilisé par des personnes ayant fait des études, et ayant donc nécessairement une connaissance des langues latine et grecque. *Orthographe barbare* (un oxymore) doit être compris ici comme ***barbarisme*** ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/barbarisme)): *Faute caractéristique d'un étranger (grec barbaros), particulièrement celle qui consiste dans l'emploi d'une forme inexistante. Par extension Faute contre la règle ou le goût; incorrection*.
En résumé, Littré reproche aux académiciens d'être incultes, au moins dans ce cas précis.

Comment: "orthographe barbare", on sent la frustration derrière tout cela

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg De la frustration? Je ne pense pas. J'y verrais plutôt de  l'indignation et de l'incompréhension. Cette phrase date du milieu du XIXᵉ siècle. L'Académie française était pourtant déjà bien conservatrice dans ses choix et privilégiait les graphies étymologiques plutôt que phonétiques, en particulier pour un mot ne faisant pas partie du vocabulaire courant pour lequel une orthographe populaire aurait pu être entérinée.

Comment: oui, vous avez raison en effet, le mot "frustration" ne se prête pas au contexte. J'étais surpris de voir ce mot, mais je comprends mieux en me mettant dans le contexte et la peau de l'auteur. On a malheureusement trop tendance à négliger la tradition de la langue de nos jours, moi y compris.

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie

Comment: @jlliagre Parlant de Littré ça peut être la réponse d'un utilisateur dans un autre forum. On ne peut que vous donner entièrement raison. L’Académie – dont Littré fut souvent un pourfendeur – a jonché son Dictionnaire d’anomalies.  Par négligence ou inconscience, elle ne les souvent pas redressées et nous devons assumer ce capital étrange.
Dans le cas de isoscèle, on remarquera que cela dépare aussi la famille qui comprend  triscèle (triskèle) et quelques autres mots techniques, et qu’il biaise la prononciation originelle. Bref, un bel exemple des aberrations académiques !

Answer (score 1):

I post here the answer in the same question that I received from another forum in case anyone is interested in.

> Comme vous le dites (citation du Littré) : on ne voit pas pourquoi, en
> un mot purement technique, l’Académie adopte l’orthographe barbare
> isocèle, et rejette l’orthographe étymologique et correcte isoscèle..
>
> On peut quand même imaginer que l’Académie a fini par accepter
> l’orthographe que l’usage avait choisie, orthographe plus simple.
> Beaucoup de lettres devenues inaudibles ont disparu au cours du temps.
> L’ancien français écrivait « hospital » ou « ospital ». Certes, en ce
> cas l’accent circonflexe rappelle une prononciation ancienne mais dans
> d’autres mots, il vient de tomber récemment (paraître devient paraitre
> par exemple). Il est vrai que beaucoup de mots ont gardé les vestiges
> d’une forme ancienne, d’autres se sont vu rajouter des lettres
> faussement étymologique (le célèbre « doigt » par exemple). Pourquoi
> ne feriez-vous pas une petite recherche pour détecter les mots qui ont
> perdu une lettre non prononcée ? Je suppose que vous en trouveriez un
> certain nombre.

A second answer from the same forum.

> On ne peut que vous donner entièrement raison. L’Académie – dont
> Littré fut souvent un pourfendeur – a jonché son Dictionnaire
> d’anomalies.  Par négligence ou inconscience, elle ne les souvent pas
> redressées et nous devons assumer ce capital étrange. Dans le cas de
> isoscèle, on remarquera que cela dépare aussi la famille qui comprend
> triscèle (triskèle) et quelques autres mots techniques, et qu’il
> biaise la prononciation originelle. Bref, un bel exemple des
> aberrations académiques !

Voir : https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/pourquoi-isocele-et-pas-isoscele/

Comment: Je trouve l'exemple de [_sçavoir_](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A1S0081) encore plus frappant, par réfection sur _scire_ plutôt que _sapere_, du 15e au 17e!